# Checking file exist in raspberry pi 2 using C language

Tags: c, file, raspberry-pi

I am new to C language and learning it by experimenting.

My challenge: I am trying to verify if a file "Command.txt" exist in a folder in raspberry pi and then I have to read the content of the file.

My Code:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>

// Pin number declarations. We're using the Broadcom chip pin numbers.
const int pwmPin = 18; // PWM LED - Broadcom pin 18, P1 pin 12
const int ledPin = 23; // Regular LED - Broadcom pin 23, P1 pin 16
const int butPin = 17; // Active-low button - Broadcom pin 17, P1 pin 11

const int pwmValue = 75; // Use this to set an LED brightness

int file_exist(char *filename)
{
  struct stat buffer;   
  return (stat(filename, &buffer) == 0);
}

int main(void) 
{
// Setup stuff:
wiringPiSetupGpio(); // Initialize wiringPi -- using Broadcom pin numbers

pinMode(pwmPin, PWM_OUTPUT); // Set PWM LED as PWM output
pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);     // Set regular LED as output
pinMode(butPin, INPUT);      // Set button as INPUT
pullUpDnControl(butPin, PUD_UP); // Enable pull-up resistor on button

printf("Blinker is running! Press CTRL+C to quit.\n");

while(1)
{
    FILE *command_file;
    char command[255];  

    while(file_exist("/home/pi/FTP/command.txt"))
    {
        command_file = fopen("/home/pi/FTP/command.txt", "r");
        fgets(command, 255, (FILE*)command_file);
        printf("1: %s\n", command );

        if(command == "First Light ON")
        {
            digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH); //Change the raspberryPi pin state to 1
        }

        else if(command == "First Light OFF")
        {
            digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW); //Change the raspberryPi pin state to 0
        }

        else 
        {
            printf("Command is not yet defined");
        }

        fclose(command_file);
    }

    while(!(file_exist("/home/pi/FTP/command.txt")))
    {           
        printf("File does not exist\n");
        delay(1000); // Wait 1s again
    }
}


return 0;


}
```

When I run this code using the gcc command in my raspberry pi, The program is executed but I only see "File does not exist" message even if the file exist in the given folder.

Please help me with the logic on this program.

Comment: This is a bad approach and subject to race-conditions. Just try open the file, if that fails, check the error (if necessary).

Comment: To help explain what @Olaf posted - what happens if the file you're checking for is deleted in the time between your call to your `file_exists()` function and your actual call to `fopen()`?  What happens if the file exists, but you don't have read access to it? And what happens if your call to `fgets()` fails?